# JavaMail: random MessageRemovedException issue

Tags: java, weblogic, jakarta-mail

I'm developing a web mail client with JavaMail 1.4 (Weblogic 10.3.5) but i'm having an issue. 
I randomly get a MessageRemovedException from `IMAPMessage.getMessageID()` even if I check that the message is not expunged.

Here is the code:

```
            Message[] msgsAll = folder.getMessages();
            Message[] msgs = null;
            for(int a=0; a<msgsAll.length; a++){
                if(!msgsAll[a].isExpunged()){
                    if(((((MimeMessage)msgsAll[a]).getMessageID()).compareTo(customMailBean.getMimeMessageId())==0)){   
                       msgs = new Message[]{msgsAll[a]};
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(msgs.length != 0){               
               folder.setFlags(msgs, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);
               folder.copyMessages(msgs, dfolder);
               folder.setFlags(msgs, new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), true);                  
            }

           folder.close(true);
           store.close();
```

Here is the exception stacktrace:

```
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.forceCheckExpunged(IMAPMessage.java:239)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadEnvelope(IMAPMessage.java:1219)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getMessageID(IMAPMessage.java:531)
at com.sanpaoloimi.sitt0.valueteam.mail.ServiceMail.moveMail(ServiceMail.java:877)
```

As you can see, i call the `IMAPMessage.getMessageID()` method only if the current message is not expunged, so why I get the MessageRemovedException? Is my client out of sync with the server?
Is this due to a concurrency bug?

In addition, the "removed" message is still in the original folder (after almost a week) and however its DELETED Flag is FALSE, this means it hasn't even been marked to be deleted! How could this be if it was "removed"?

Thanks.

Comment: From the documentation:

Messages that are externally expunged by another source are marked "expunged" and return true for the isExpunged() method, but they are not removed from the Folder until an explicit expunge() is done on the Folder.


Could that be the case for you?

Comment: Hi Amir, the message is still in the original Folder after a week, anyway its DELETED flag is FALSE, so it hasn't been marked to be deleted.

Comment: The isExpunged method doesn't check with the server to see if the message has been expunged, it only checks a local flag that is set when the server notifies the client that the message has been expunged.  If the getMessageID call on the server fails, it checks to find out if the message has been expunged, even though it hasn't seen the notification from the server yet.  Anyway, there's an inherent race condition in what you're doing, since the message could've been expunged right after you checked.  Your best bet is to catch the MessageRemovedException.

Comment: As to why you're getting this exception even though the message hasn't been expunged, there could be a bug in JavaMail or there could be a bug in the server.  We need to see the protocol trace that might show more information about why the getMessageID call is failing.  Also, you might want to simplify your code by using Folder.search to find the matching message.

Comment: Bill, we are having this issue in Production environment where we can't print the protocol trace and we didn't manage to reproduce the bug in testing environment. Anyway, I modified my code by adding a reference to the original JavaMail Message to our custom message bean, so I don't have to search for it. In addition, I'm properly catching the MessageRemovedException. I hope these solve the problem. Thanks for your help.